# AngularJS test $q.all service jasmine with multi urls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I want write to some unit test for my app and I'm stuck when want write test for my service.

My service code below:

```
function CurrenciesService($http, $q)
    {

        return {
            getCurrencies: function ()
            {
                var rates = [];

                var urls = [{url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/usd/today/'}, {url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/eur/today/'},
                    {url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/gbp/today/'}];

                var urlsCalls = [];
                angular.forEach(urls, function (url)
                {
                    urlsCalls.push($http.get(url.url));
                });
                return $q.all(urlsCalls)
                        .then(function (result)
                        {
                            angular.forEach(result, function (rate)
                            {
                                var currency = {};
                                currency.code = rate.data.code;
                                currency.sell = rate.data.rates[0].bid;
                                currency.buy = rate.data.rates[0].ask;
                                currency.date = rate.data.rates[0].effectiveDate;
                                rates.push(currency);
                            });
                            return rates;
                        });
            }
        };
    }
```

and my unit test below:

```
describe('CurrenciesService', function ()
{
'use strict';

var CurrenciesMock;
var httpMock;
var qMock;
var httpBackend;
var fakeRates = [];
var urls;
var urlsCalls = [];

beforeEach(module('cinkciarzTraining'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_,_CurrenciesService_, _$http_, _$q_)
{
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    qMock = _$q_;
    httpMock =_$http_;
    CurrenciesMock = _CurrenciesService_;

    urls = [{url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/usd/today/'}, {url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/eur/today/'},
        {url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/gbp/today/'}];
    angular.forEach(urls, function (url)
    {
        urlsCalls.push(httpMock.get(url.url));
    });
    fakeRates = [
        {
            buy: 4.1635, code: 'USD', date: '2017-01-20', sell: 4.0811
        }, {
            buy: 4.4112, code: 'EUR', date: '2017-01-20', sell: 4.3238
        }, {
            buy: 5.123, code: 'GBP', date: '2017-01-20', sell: 5.0216
        }
    ];



}));

describe('getCurencies', function ()
{
    describe('when call requests', function ()
    {
        beforeEach(function ()
        {
            httpBackend.whenGET(urls[0].url).respond(fakeRates[0]);
        });
        it('should return rates', function ()
        {
            CurrenciesMock.getCurrencies().then(function(result){
                expect(result).toEqual(fakeRates);
            });
            httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });
});
});
```

When I run test I got error:

```
 Error: Unexpected request: GET https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/eur/today/    
No more request expected in app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 1421)
$httpBackend@app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1421:90
sendReq@app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11947:21
serverRequest@app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11742:23
processQueue@app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16606:30
app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16622:39
$eval@app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17913:28
$digest@app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17727:36
flush@app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1813:45
test/unit/services/currenciesService.spec.js:54:34
```

I never do test unit for $http and I don't know how write this test. Could someone can me explain what wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

you should call httpBackend.flush(); as many times there is a network request.

in your case 
add a global variable first

```
var count=0;

urls = [{url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/usd/today/'}, {url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/eur/today/'},
    {url: 'https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/gbp/today/'}];
```

after this add valueto a global variable

```
count=urls.length;
```

then in that case you will call httpBackend.flush();
according to that count.

Comment: I'm do this `httpBackend.flush(count)` but this not work, still show the same error.

Comment: call httpBackend.flush() as many times as specified by count using a for loop for(i=0;i<count:i++){$httpBackend.flush()}

Comment: Is the same. But in beforeEach I call only first url, so why should i use httpBackend.flush() many times?